# How to display multiple uploaded images in row

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to upload images from a file and display them in rows.
My code below displays images one below the other, whereas I want them to be displayed as 3/4 images in each row.

This is what I tried:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Images in a Row</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets1/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
        <p><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('statusMsg'); ?></p>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Choose Files</label>
                <div id="rowimg">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="userFiles[]" multiple/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="submit" name="fileSubmit" value="UPLOAD"/>
            </div>
        </form>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <?php if(!empty($files)): foreach($files as $file): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/files/'.$file['file_name']); ?>" alt="" >
                <p>Uploaded On <?php echo date("j M Y",strtotime($file['created'])); ?></p><br>            
            <?php endforeach; else: ?>
            <p>Image(s) not found.....</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
                  </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I researched for some solution in StackOverflow and got CSS code, but it gives me the same output all images one below the other :(

CSS file:`bootstrap.css`

```
#rowimg {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 5000px;
    height:200px;
}
```

[Here is an image of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKgEG.png)

Comment: Using bootstrap class without the bootstrap css will be the first thing to fix

Comment: I skipped the bootstrap class links while pasting the code here.

Comment: Can you post rendered HTML code starting from the `container` div.

Comment: Oh, well in that case, I see that you have a closing `</a>` but I don't see any opening `<a>` - It makes me wonder how it all render by the browser.

Comment: @DanPhilip Please forgive me for the inconvenience as I am new to all this I do not know how the rendering of HTML is done. If you could guide me I would do it.

Comment: try changing col-md-4 to col-md-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well excuse me for my "mistakes" as you wrote in your last [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573004/how-to-display-multiple-uploaded-images-in-row/43574599#comment74197140_43573004), but they weren't my mistakes, I can only see the code you post, and in your original question there wasn't any bootstrap css, and then after you eddited it I noticed that you had a closing `</a>` without a matching `<a>` tag.

After this passive-aggressive introduction, let's get back to the code `:)`

**What is wrong with your current code?** Currently you're creating a single `column` inside a `row`, and under that column you create a single `thumbnail` and append to it all the images. This what's causing the images to display horizontally instead of vertically.

**How it should be fixed?** You need to spit your thumbnails into chunks of X items. For each chunk you need a separate **row**,  and for each item you need a separate **column**.

You have the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- HTML -->
    </div>
</div>
```

From that I can conclude that you want to put 3 thumbnail's on each row (3 * 4 == 12). So you need to split your array of thumbnails into chunks with 3 thumbnails on each chunk. You do it using [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$thumbnails = array_chunk( $files, 3 );
```

Now you have in `$thumbnails` a multidimensional array, where each dimension has 3 thumbnails.

Next, you need to iterate over the `$thumbnails` multidimensional array, and build your html structure correctly:

```
<?php if(!empty($files)) { 
    foreach($thumbnails as $files) { ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach($files as $file) { ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/files/'.$file['file_name']); ?>" alt="" >
                        <p>Uploaded On <?php echo date("j M Y",strtotime($file['created'])); ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p>Image(s) not found.....</p>
<?php } ?>
```

What the above code does is to iterate over each chunk of thumbnails and create a wrapping `<div class="row"></div>` for the thumbnails. Next, it iterate over the thumbnails and print each one inside a container of 1/3 of the row width (`class="col-md-4"`), and inside that container it pint the structure of the thumbnail itself.

Comment: Thnx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the `.thumbnail` class css to `display:inline-block;` or `float:left;`?

Oh, and your using the bootstrap `col-md-4` class wrong.

To divide your content into columns the divs that have the bootstrap class `col-md-*` need for the `col-md-*` to total 12.
If you want 4 columns then the code should look something like this.

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <img>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <img>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <img>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <img>
 </div>
```